# Java 8 - fill ArrayList

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a better way to fill an `ArrayList` like this (I have done it like this in Java 7):

```
List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers = new ArrayList<>();
scheduleIntervalContainers.add(scheduleIntervalContainer);
```

Comment: What's wrong with that way?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but Java 8 features are not something I have a lot of expertise in. But when I look at your code, the only thing that makes it look long and cumbersome are long variable names. Personally I wouldn't shorten those either because I'd rather long descriptive names and self documenting code over brevity and so will anyone who has to maintain the code.

Comment: `List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(scheduleIntervalContainer));`

Comment: @Alexis C.: for a single element list, there is `Collections.singletonList(…))` which spares you from creating an array…

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. You talk about “filling” but are actually only adding a single element. What better way to add a single element to a list than invoking a method named `add` on that list can you imagine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fill a `List`, it is possible to generate an infinite `Stream` using [`Stream.generate(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) and then limit the number of results with [`limit(maxSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-).

For example, to fill a `List` of 10 new `ScheduleIntervalContainer` objects:

```
List<ScheduleIntervalContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers = 
        Stream.generate(ScheduleIntervalContainer::new).limit(10).collect(toList());
```

The `generate` method takes a `Supplier`: in this case, the supplier is a method reference creating new instance of `ScheduleIntervalContainer` each time.