# Java 8 - what is the correct way to fill an arraylist with the same object using Stream API?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I am new with Stream API and I am looking for more elegant and shortest way to fill an ArrayList **with the same object** using Stream API equivalent to this code:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

int maxLimitValue = 70; //for example
for(int i=0; i<=maxLimitValue; i++){
   someObjectList.add(someObject);
}
```

I have seen many different solutions for my current task:

[This variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33142064/5331196) is almost what I want, but there is an auto-generation of the objects, but I need to use the same object created once.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600690/5331196) is also almost what I need, but I am no sure about this copying of objects and the returned List type **is not** ArrayList (it returned the CopiesList type, which cannot be added to the ArrayList in the future operations).

p.s. maybe it's possible duplicate, but I really can't find the correct and short way to do this using Stream API.

**Update (assylias additions):**

Yes, I agree with you about this variant:

```
List<SomeObject> list = Collections.nCopies(70, someObject);
```

But, when I am opening this method:

```
public static <T> List<T> nCopies(int n, T o) {
        if (n < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List length = " + n);
        return new CopiesList<>(n, o);
    }
```

And as we see - it returning the CopiesList object, not ArrayList.
Also, as the other lists, it is extending the AbstractList:

```
private static class CopiesList<E>
        extends AbstractList<E>
        implements RandomAccess, Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2739099268398711800L;

        final int n;
        final E element;

        CopiesList(int n, E e) {
            assert n >= 0;
            this.n = n;
            element = e;
        }
...}
```

It's not quite ArrayList, but thank's for your suggestions and advice whithout an empty words and off-topic comments, I will use your solution.

Comment: The second link you posted (`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(60, 0))`) does exactly what you need, and it does create an `ArrayList`.

Comment: What's the point of storing 70 times a reference on the same object ?

Comment: Spotted, this is the one large solution to solve some JavaFX issue in the TableView+Pagination integration with Hibernate and Spring (70 is for example, only).
It is a very long time to explain about this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build the stream manually:

```
List<SomeObject> list = Stream.generate(() -> someObject).limit(70).collect(toList());
//or if you want to make sure you get an ArrayList:
List<SomeObject> list = Stream.generate(() -> someObject).limit(70).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Although creating a stream just for that purpose is probably inefficient and I would probably go with what @Eran suggested:

```
List<SomeObject> list = Collections.nCopies(70, someObject);
//or if you want to make sure you get an ArrayList:
List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<> (Collections.nCopies(70, someObject));
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I have updated the question, maybe you can add something to this part?

Comment: You can always write `new ArrayList<> (Collections.nCopies(70, someObject))` but why do you want an ArrayList?

Comment: When I am trying to add to this list (list created from nCopies) another list(another ArrayList) by method addAll() - I am getting an UnsupportedOperationException, but if I adding list from nCopies to another - all is working fine, so I think you were right - it's not a point now.
Thank's a lot! Really helped!

Comment: Note that the stream solution using the `toList()` collector *happens* to return an `ArrayList`, but doesn’t guaranty it. You’ll have to use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, if it really has to be a an `ArrayList`. But even using streams, `Collections.nCopies(70, someObject).stream()` is the potentially more efficient stream source. It’s equivalent to `IntStream.range(0, 70).mapToObj(i -> someObject)`…

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use IntStream.range() and map every int to the same object with mapToObj method and collect it to a list