# Using Stream API to fill up a Collection

Tags: java

I'm just learning the `java.util.stream` API and I'm looking for a way to quickly fill up a Collection with some data.

I've come up with this code to add 5 random numbers:

```
List<Integer> lottery = Stream.of(random.nextInt(90), random.nextInt(90), random.nextInt(90),random.nextInt(90),
random.nextInt(90)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That would be however a problem in case I have to add hundreds of items. Is there a more concise way to do it using the `java.util.stream` API?

(I could obviously loop in the ordinary way...)

Thanks

Comment: check out `IntStream.range`. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793191/3959856

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 - what is the correct way to fill an arraylist with the same object using Stream API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258194/java-8-what-is-the-correct-way-to-fill-an-arraylist-with-the-same-object-using)

Comment: IntStream.range(0,5).map(i -> random.nextInt(90)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Answer from duplicate noted by @ashwinsakthi : `Stream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(90)).limit(5).collect(toList());`

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate, but see Olivier's answer - this has a special wrinkle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the stream API only makes things more complicated vs. a regular loop, but you *could* create an `IntStream` (or `Stream<Integer>` depending on where you convert the `int` to `Integer`) that generates infinite random numbers with

```
IntStream rndStream = IntStream.generate(() -> rnd.nextInt(90));
```

Now you can use `limit()` to create non-infinite substreams that can be collected, such as

```
rndStream.limit(5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However this is just stream trickery and has no advantages over say having a method called `List<Integer> getRandoms(int number)` with a regular loop inside.

---

There's no reason to use the code displayed in this answer as it's less readable and more complex than alternatives. This just demonstrates how to get finite amounts of elements from an infinitely generated stream.

Comment: @Carla there's nothing cool about writing unreadable overly complex code. Use streams and regular loops where they make sense. Streams are **not** a replacement for "old" loops.

Answer (score 4):

## Use [`Random.ints(long, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int))

Everyone else on this page is generating the stream because they can, but Java already has such an out of the box method, [`Random.ints(long, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)), available since Java 8 (and therefore the beginning of streams).

Just use it like this:

```
List<Integer> lottery = rnd.ints(5, 0, 90)
                           .boxed()
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The instruction `rnd.ints(5L, 0, 90)` means: "create a stream of 5 integers between 0 (included) and 90 (excluded)". So if you want 100 numbers instead of 5, just change `5` to `100`.

Comment: Wow, great method - I did not know about that. Makes you think about discoverability of stuff in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,100).forEach(value->randomList.add(random.nextInt(90)));
```