# Concise way to fill up an ArrayList with data

Tags: java

I need to fill an ArrayList with some (random) data. I wonder if Java 8/9 allows a more concise way than this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
for (int ii=0;ii<100;ii++)
list.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140535/java-8-fill-arraylist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably this will do:

```
Supplier<String> supplier = () -> UUID.randomUUID().toString();
List<String> list = Stream.generate(supplier).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ironically, the old-fashioned approach from the question is way shorter than your answer (96 vs. 151 chars, including linefeeds), but that's not your fault ;-)

Comment: There are so many possibilities yeah this is another one but not concise  :P

Comment: To make it shorter, you don't have to create a `supplier`-variable. You could just put the lambda-function as argument into `generate`

Comment: Code golf shows us that Java was not really intended to be concise ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes not more concise, however I've learnt something new though!